# Eclipse import SVN project as Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using the SVN plugin in my Eclipse to fetch code from our repository. Apparently some files weren't checked in correctly and the Eclipse project now looks like a simple project.

I know all source files are there, but now way to get this running as an Android project. Is there a way to "convert" my project to an Android project correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your .project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name><PROJECT NAME></name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Edit the .classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Edit/create project.properties file

```
target=android-<API LEVEL>
```

Now Ecplise should regognize your project as an Android project.

Comment: Got that, no it is complaining about gen/ not being a source folder.

Comment: Did you refresh a project, and made a clean then a build? Also create gen folder in the file system manually, if that does not exist.

Comment: It seems to be OK now. I tried refreshing, cleaning and fixing a zillion times before, just to get a new error each time. I completely started over, and now it seems to be OK (fingers crossed).

Comment: Almost... it doesn't create .class files anymore.

Comment: Does it show any error in the Problems tab or in the Console?

Comment: Nothing. It just creates the empty APK file and crashes the tablet with a `ClassNotFound` exception.

Comment: I see. Please go to your Build Path in Project properties, Order and Export tab, and make sure every folder is selected excluding the Android platform lib. Also the order shoud be src, gen, Android Private Libraries, Android Dependencies.

Comment: It is all checked. My src and gen dirs are on top (with a - sign, instead of a checkmark though).

Comment: It's getting weirder... Try deleting the contents of the build folder and then clean and rebuild.

Comment: Did that. Nothing. it just creates a res/ dir and copies the manifest in the bin dir.

Comment: My bad. Forgot the "javabuilder" build command in the .project file.